# what is python interpreter bytecode languages

Tags: python

I know the python interpreter is written in C and produces bytecode to be run on the python virtual machine also written in C (right?).

I am talking about python of https://www.python.org/ interpreter.
so the question is :
what is python bytecode language ? **C ? python ? ASM ?**
and what will execute this bytecodes in virtual machine ? is it a language ?
and  when it interpret this line , what are bytecodes likes ?

```
>>> print("HI")
HI
```

I also find this page :
[http://svn.python.org/view/](http://svn.python.org/view)

Comment: There is *a* Python interpreter written in C, but it's not the only one. This question is much too broad as it stands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between assembly code and bytecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782415/what-is-the-difference-between-assembly-code-and-bytecode)

Comment: The answers there aren't supremely excellent but it's fundamentally the same question. See also e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2203296/874188) to a similar question about Java.

Answer (score 2):

Python bytecode is basically the *instruction set* of the Python virtual machine, its [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code), if you will.

Like the machine code used by CPUs like x86 and ARM, it is a "language" that is not meant to be human-readable. It is meant to be run efficiently.

The `dis` module acts like a "disassembler" converting the binary instructions into something human readable.

Answer (score 1):

to have an overview of bytecode, use dis module

Example:

```
def a():
    print("HI")
```

now :

```
import dis
dis.dis(a)
```

Then you show the byte-code.